# Python IDE with autocomplete mechanism parsing docstring

Tags: python, autocomplete, pydev, docstring

so far, I only found PyCharm as being able to parse docstring in order to determine a variable's type and enable autocompletion for that variable, e.g.:

```
def func(arg):
    """
    epydoc style docstring

    @type arg: str
    @rtype: str
    """
    arg.#<-autocomplete enabled, because we know it is a string#
    ...

func('test').#<-autocomplete enabled here too#
```

Are there other (preferably free) Python IDE that have this functionality? I tried Pydev and Spyder, which do not seem to.

Comment: I just deleted my answer recommending PyScripter (Windows only). I tested and it doesn't support exactly what you're asking for. (Thanks for including a clear example so I could test.) This is a neat feature I should submit it as a feature request to PyScripter. If there is an IDE that you would like to see support this, you could submit a feature request to the project. (If it's an open source IDE you could try to implement it yourself.)

Comment: Since I use PyDev (Eclipse) a lot, I would like this IDE to support this feature. I added 'PyDev' to tags, which seems to be the standard way to submit a question/request to PyDev developers. Unfortunately my skills are not sufficient to implement this. It must be very hard to manage linked types, e.g.: `@type arg: L{MyClass}`. But as I wrote, PyCharm IDE does it!

Comment: This does work in the latest version of PyDev (was added during the last year).

Answer (score 2):

This is something that was added on PyDev. The latest release (3.3.3) had a small fix for it, but it should be working since 2.8.0.

Answer (score -1):

I'm now evaluating PyCharm, and I really like it exactly for this features.
Also, it can run under linux and windows, which is another advantage.
I don't know any other Python IDE with this autocompletion mechanism.

Unfortunatelly PyCharm is not open source..

Answer (score -1):

Indeed there is a free solution:

Try [Jedi](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi)! It should understand epydoc type annotations.

At the moment there are plugins for VIM, Emacs and Sublime. Spyder [is considering](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/102) to switch from Rope to Jedi. But that's going to take a while.